# Put Glassfish in behind

Tags: proxy, glassfish

I have a working Glassfish application, that provides web services, access to JMS queues, servlets, JSP pages.

Is it possible to put "something" in front of Glassfish, so that the Glassfish server will be hidden from the Internet? I know I can put Apache HTTPD in front of Glassfish and can redirect access to HTML, JSP pages, servlets, web services from Apache to Glasfish. But I don't know how to do that for accessing JMS queues. Any suggestions?